# Rancher & Docker Failed to get ping from agent

Tags: docker, rancher, swarm

I am facing another issue with Rancher & Docker.

I've installed the Rancher Server and then, in another server, a Rancher Agent using the command provided from Rancher Server. 
I can see the node in the host section but every 5 minutes rancher shows the message "Reconnecting" to the node.

I've checked the rancher server logs and it shows the following:

```
[i.c.p.a.s.ping.impl.PingMonitorImpl ] Failed to get ping from agent [6] count [3]
```

and no more information.

Could you please shed some light on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Which Rancher version you are using ? If it is old then try again after upgrading it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the load balancer that is supporting the Rancher URL doesn't support WebSockets.

Please try bypassing your load balancer temporarily by pointing your Rancher URL directly to one of the Rancher servers. If the issues goes away then work with your networking team to rules to support WebSockets.

Side note: Rancher v1.6 is very old and is EOL. You should really start moving to Rancher v2.x.